# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze, attributeerror

I am trying to make a script executable with `py2exe`.

Here is my `setup.py` code:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Email.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Email",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["aura.png"]}},
    executables = executables

    )
```

And I run this from my cmd and here is the execution:

```
G:\Grade 12 Project>python setup.py build running build running build_exe creating directory build\exe.win32-2.7 copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win32-2.7\Email.exe copying C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.dll
-> build\exe.win32-2.7\python27.dll Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    executables = executables   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 623, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 225, in
_FreezeExecutable
    self._AddVersionResource(exe)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 165, in
_AddVersionResource
    trademarks = exe.trademarks)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 759, in
__init__
    parts = version.split(".") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Also in my build folder , when I run `Email.exe`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named __startup__
```

Comment: I think you have to provide version number also. It is trying to split "x.x.x" type of string but since you haven't provided it, it's throwing error.

Comment: @amin , That's a trivial edit.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi , version number of?

Comment: Inside the setup function. Check this: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi , I am sorry.I dint get you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi said, you need to pass a `version='x.y.z'` parameter into the setup call, e.g:

```
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Email",
    options={
        "build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
        "include_files":["aura.png"]}},
    executables = executables,
    version='1.0.0'
)
```

It's not valid to call `setup` without a version number.

Are you trying to run this from the command line or from the GUI? If from the GUI you may need to call `Executable("Email.py", base="Win32GUI")` as per [the docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html) in order for it to work, so that *might* be the problem. But it would help to see the full traceback.